# mySQL InnoDB foreign key constraints

Tags: mysql, constraints, innodb

I've been searching around for quite a while now and can't find a definitive answer.

I have two tables:
'players' - Store the basic account info for players of a game
and 'player_stats' - Stores stats of the player

I have a primary key in the 'players' table, and a foreign key in the 'player_stats' table, which references the primary key in the 'players' table.

I want to make it so if I try and delete a record from the stats table, it is denied, and if I delete a record in the players table, their corresponding stats record gets removed. I only seem to be able to do one or the other (on delete cascade on the foreign key allows me to delete a record in the stats table, and 'restrict' denies me from deleting a player.. wrong way round..).

Again: I want it so if I try to delete the PARENT row ('players'), it cascades to the 'player_stats' table, but if I try and delete a row from stats, it's denied.

Thanks.

Comment: "if I try and delete a record from the stats table, it is denied" --- just don't give the `DELETE` permission to the user then? Denying deletion isn't about referential integrity or constraints but about permissions.

Comment: I need to be able to delete rows from 'players' though.. I can't deny deletion for a user..

Comment: "I need to be able to delete rows from 'players'" --- "but if I try and delete a row from stats, it's denied" --- these 2 statements don't play together well

Comment: Why? It makes sense.. I want to be unable to delete the stats, and if I delete the player, the stats get deleted with it.

Comment: what's wrong with my proposal? I proposed to disallow to `DELETE` from a single table

Comment: 'players' and 'stats' are two different tables. I want to be able to delete players, but not stats. If I DO delete a player, I want it to cascade and delete the stats too.

Comment: So? Drop `DELETE` permission for a single table

Comment: Oh, I was not aware that was possible.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html#grant-table-privileges